# Canvas game shooting and selecting issue + viewport

Tags: javascript, canvas

I got a problem with shooting in my canvas game. When I shoot bullet to target(enemy) and there is no other enemies on front of, bullet goes right, but when enemies are in front of player and they're covering straight path to target, bullet dissapears when met first enemy. I want bullet to go over enemies straight to target, and I have no idea how to achieve that.

2. Other problem is with that crosshair which I made, It can select multiple enemies, but I want to be able to select only one enemy. Any ideas how to deal with that? I'm almost sure, this is a small problem.
3. I want to make viewport then, but when I implement something from internet, it just doesn't work, and, I'm not just asking, I really tried hard to make this viewport, also like resolving other problems I mentioned. I hope you can help me out with some of these problems, thanks.

```js
var ctx = $("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d'),
    cHeight = canvas.height = 800,
    cWidth = canvas.width = 1300,
    canvasOffset = $('#canvas').offset(),
    offsetX = canvasOffset.left,
    offsetY = canvasOffset.top,
    frameCounter = 0,
    enemyList = [],
    bulletList = [],
    spawningEnemies_FLAG = true,
    isLeftMouseButtonHeld_FLAG = false,
    isAnyEnemySelected_FLAG = false,
    cursors = ['default', 'pointer'],
    enemiesOnMap = 10;


ctx.font = '22px Arial';


var sharedBehaviour = {

    x: (cWidth / 2) - (cWidth / 8) + randomNumberFromRange(1, (cWidth / 8)),
    y: (cHeight / 2) - (cHeight / 8) + randomNumberFromRange(1, (cHeight / 8)),
    id: undefined,
    type: 'entity',
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    fillColor: '#E15258',
    targetX: null,
    targetY: null,
    bulletSpeed: 1,
    aimAngle: null,
    circleRadius: null,
    circleColor: 'black',
    circleWidth: 1,

    // Statistics
    hp: 10,
    shield: 0,
    speed: 1,

    update( type ) {
        if( type === 'player' ) {
            enemyList.forEach( enemy => {
                if ( enemy.isMouseOver() ) {
                    if( isLeftMouseButtonHeld_FLAG ) {
                        player.targetX = player.targetY = null;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        // if there is target
        if( this.targetX !== null ) {
            // Find out distance to target
            var distanceX = this.targetX - this.x; // distance on X axis
            var distanceY = this.targetY - this.y; // distance on Y axis
            var distanceToTarget = Math.sqrt( distanceX*distanceX + distanceY*distanceY ); // distance

            // If distance is smaller or equal speed, then just set position
            if( distanceToTarget <= this.speed ) {
                this.x = this.targetX;
                this.y = this.targetY;
                // Then reset
                this.targetX = this.targetY = null;
            } else { // If distance is bigger than speed, so we want to move with speed
                distanceX = distanceX / distanceToTarget;
                distanceY = distanceY / distanceToTarget;
                distanceX = distanceX * this.speed;
                distanceY = distanceY * this.speed;
                this.x += distanceX;
                this.y += distanceY;
            }
        }
    },
    draw( ) {
        drawRect( this.x - this.width/2,
                  this.y - this.height/2,
                  this.width,
                  this.height, 
                  this.fillColor );
    },
    highlight( ) {
        crosshair( this.x - this.width/2, this.y - this.height/2, this.width, this.height, 
                   20, 25, // radius1, radius2
                   6, // endLineWidth
                   1, 2, // circle1Width, circle2Width
                   2, 2, 2, 2, // topLineWidth, rightLineWidth, bottomLineWidth, leftLineWidth
                   '#E15258', '#E15258', // circle1Color, circle2Color
                   '#C25975' ); // linesColor
    },
    isColliding( entity ) {
        // Collision: rect to rect
        return testCollisionRectRect( this, entity );
    },
    drawCircle( ) {
        drawCircle( this.x, this.y, this.circleRadius, this.circleWidth, this.circleColor );
    }

};



var player = Object.assign({}, sharedBehaviour, { 
    x: cWidth/2 - 10,
    y: cHeight/2 - 10,
    id: 980722,
    type: 'player',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    fillColor: '#82d877',
    bulletSpeed: 1,
    circleRadius: 200,
    circleColor: 'black',
    circleWidth: 1,
    pressingC: false,

    // Player stats
    name: 'player1',
    pd: 0,
    hp: 10,
    speed: 2.5
});



function createEnemy( x, y, id, width, height, fillColor, speed, type ) {

    var newEnemy = Object.assign({}, sharedBehaviour, {
        x,
        y,
        id,
        width,
        height,
        type,
        fillColor,
        mouseX: null,
        mouseY: null,
        isHighlighted: false,
        isClicked: false,
        circleRadius: 50,
        circleColor: 'red',
        circleWidth: 1,
        
        // Statistics
        hp: 100,
        shield: 0,
        speed,

        setTarget( entity ) {
            this.targetX = entity.x + randomNumberFromRange(-50, 50);
            this.targetY = entity.y + randomNumberFromRange(-50, 50);
        },
        isOnPlayer( val ) {
            // Check if enemy is on player
            var distanceX = player.x - this.x;
            var distanceY = player.y - this.y;
            return Math.sqrt( distanceX*distanceX + distanceY*distanceY ) < val;
        },
        isMouseOver( ) {
            return (this.mouseX + this.width/2 >= this.x && this.mouseX + this.width/2 <= this.x + this.width && this.mouseY + this.height/2 >= this.y && this.mouseY + this.height/2 <= this.y + this.height);
        }
    });

    enemyList.push( newEnemy );

}


function createBullet( actor ) {
    var newBullet = Object.assign({}, sharedBehaviour, {
        x: actor.x,
        y: actor.y,
        height: 7,
        width: 7,
        aimAngle: actor.aimAngle,
        fillColor: 'green',
        spdX: Math.cos(actor.aimAngle/180*Math.PI)*8,
        spdY: Math.sin(actor.aimAngle/180*Math.PI)*8,
        update ( ) {
            this.x += this.spdX;
            this.y += this.spdY;
        }
    });

    bulletList.push( newBullet );
}


function newGame( ) {
    // Reset all to its defaults
    player.hp = 10;
    frameCounter = 0;
    enemyList = [];
    bulletList = [];
    spawningEnemies_FLAG = true;
    isLeftMouseButtonHeld_FLAG = false;

    // Spawning enemies
    for( i=0; i < randomNumberFromRange(15, 25); i++ ) {
        createEnemy( randomNumberFromRange(0, cWidth), randomNumberFromRange(0, cHeight), 'str' + (i+1), randomNumberFromRange(12, 18), randomNumberFromRange(12, 18), 'red', 1, 's' );
        createEnemy( randomNumberFromRange(0, cWidth), randomNumberFromRange(0, cHeight), 'lor' + (i+1), randomNumberFromRange(10, 16), randomNumberFromRange(10, 16), 'lightblue', 1.5, 'l' ); 
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}





function update( ) {
    frameCounter++;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cWidth,cHeight);

    enemyList.forEach( enemy => {
        enemy.update();
    });

    // Update bullet position and remove if goes out of canvas
    bulletList.forEach( bullet => {
        bullet.update();
        if ( bullet.x < 0 || bullet.x > cWidth || bullet.y < 0 || bullet.y > cHeight) {
            bulletList.remove(bullet);
        }
    });

    player.update('player');

    enemyList.forEach( enemy => {

        if( enemy.isHighlighted ) {
            if( enemy.isMouseOver() ) {
                enemy.draw();
                enemy.highlight();
            } else {
                enemy.draw()
            }
        } else {
            enemy.draw();
        }

        if( enemy.isClicked ) {
            enemy.draw();
            enemy.highlight();
        } else {
            enemy.draw();
        }


        if ( Math.random() < ( 1 / 15 ) ) { // 1 in 25 chance to look for player about once every 0.25 sec
            if ( enemy.isOnPlayer( player.circleRadius ) ) {
                if ( ! (enemy.isOnPlayer( 50 )) ) {
                    enemy.setTarget( player );
                }
            }
        }

        if ( Math.random() < ( 1 / 800 )) { // 1 in 500 chance to look for player about once every 5 sec
            if ( ! (enemy.isOnPlayer( player.circleRadius )) ) {
                enemy.setTarget( enemy );
            }
        }

        if ( enemy.isOnPlayer(player.circleRadius/4 ) ) {
            enemy.targetX = enemy.targetY = null; // Reset enemy target
        }

        // If bullet has collision with enemy, rcemove both and add reward
        bulletList.forEach( bullet => {
            if ( testCollisionRectRect(enemy, bullet) ) {

                 if( enemy.isClicked ) {
                enemy.hp -= 5;
                bulletList.remove(bullet);
                 if ( enemy.hp <= 0 ) {
                    enemyList.remove(enemy);

                }
            }
               
            }
        });

    });

    bulletList.forEach( bullet => {
        bullet.draw();
    });

    player.draw();
    player.drawCircle();

    if ( frameCounter % 500 === 0 && spawningEnemies_FLAG ) {
        createEnemy( randomNumberFromRange(0, cWidth), randomNumberFromRange(0, cHeight), 'str' + (i+1), randomNumberFromRange(12, 18), randomNumberFromRange(12, 18), 'red', 1, 's' );
        createEnemy( randomNumberFromRange(0, cWidth), randomNumberFromRange(0, cHeight), 'lor' + (i+1), randomNumberFromRange(10, 16), randomNumberFromRange(10, 16), 'lightblue', 1.5, 'l' );
    }

    if ( enemyList.length === enemiesOnMap ) {
        spawningEnemies_FLAG = false;
    } else {
        spawningEnemies_FLAG = true;
    }

    ctx.fillText(player.hp + " hp", 10, 25);
    ctx.fillText('Map 1', cWidth-70, 25);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


document.onmousedown = function( mouse ) {
    isLeftMouseButtonHeld_FLAG = true;
    setPlayerTargetAndCheckAvailableArea( mouse );
}

document.onmouseup = function( mouse ) {
    isLeftMouseButtonHeld_FLAG = false;
}

document.onmousemove = function( mouse ) {
    if ( isLeftMouseButtonHeld_FLAG ) {
        setPlayerTargetAndCheckAvailableArea( mouse );
    }
    
    var mouseX = mouse.clientX - document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var mouseY = mouse.clientY - document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect().top;

    var newX, newY;

    enemyList.forEach( enemy => {
        if( enemy.isClicked ) {
            isAnyEnemySelected_FLAG = true;
            newX = enemy.x;
            newY = enemy.y;
        }
    });

    if( isAnyEnemySelected_FLAG ) {
        newX -= player.x;
        newY -= player.y;
        player.aimAngle = Math.atan2(newY, newX) / Math.PI * 180;
    } else {
        isAnyEnemySelected_FLAG = false;
        mouseX -= player.x;
        mouseY -= player.y;
        player.aimAngle = Math.atan2(mouseY, mouseX) / Math.PI * 180;
    }


    var mousexX = parseInt(mouse.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseyY = parseInt(mouse.clientY - offsetY);

    var currentCursor = 0;

    enemyList.forEach( enemy => {
        enemy.mouseX = mousexX;
        enemy.mouseY = mouseyY;

        if(enemy.isMouseOver()) {
            currentCursor = 1;
            if(enemy.isClicked) {
                enemy.isHighlighted = false;
            } else {
                enemy.isHighlighted = true;
            }
        } else {
            enemy.isHighlighted = false;
        }

    });

    canvas.style.cursor = cursors[currentCursor];
}

document.onclick = function( mouse ) {
    var mousexX = parseInt(mouse.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseyY = parseInt(mouse.clientY - offsetY);

    enemyList.forEach( enemy => {
        enemy.mouseX = mousexX;
        enemy.mouseY = mouseyY;

        if(enemy.isMouseOver()) {
            if(enemy.isHighlighted) {
                enemy.isHighlighted = false;
                enemy.isClicked = true;
            } else {
                enemy.isClicked = false;
            }
        } else {
            enemy.isClicked = false;
        }
    });
}


document.onkeydown = function ( key ) {
    switch(key.keyCode) {
        case 67:
            player.pressingC = true;
            break;
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function ( key ) {
    switch(key.keyCode) {
        case 67:
            player.pressingC = false;
            if( isAnyEnemySelected_FLAG ) {
                createBullet( player );
            }
            break;
    }
}



function setPlayerTargetAndCheckAvailableArea ( mouse ) {
    player.targetX = mouse.clientX - document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect().left;
    player.targetY = mouse.clientY - document.getElementById('canvas').getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if (player.targetX < player.width/2) {
        player.targetX = player.width/2; 
    }

    if (player.targetX > cWidth - player.width/2) { 
        player.targetX = cWidth - player.width/2 
    }

    if (player.targetY < player.height/2) { 
        player.targetY = player.height/2; 
    }

    if (player.targetY > cHeight - player.height/2) { 
        player.targetY = cHeight - player.height/2 
    }
}



function randomNumberFromRange( min, max ) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function testCollisionRectRect( rectangle1, rectangle2 ) {
    return rectangle1.x - rectangle1.width/2 <= rectangle2.x - rectangle2.width/2 + rectangle2.width
        && rectangle2.x - rectangle2.width/2 <= rectangle1.x - rectangle1.width/2 + rectangle1.width
        && rectangle1.y - rectangle1.height/2 <= rectangle2.y - rectangle2.height/2 + rectangle2.height
        && rectangle2.y - rectangle2.height/2 <= rectangle1.y - rectangle1.height/2 + rectangle1.height;
}

Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
}; // Function to pop specific element drom array by value


function crosshair( x, y, width, height, radius1, radius2, endLineWidth, circle1Width, circle2Width, topLineWidth, rightLineWidth, bottomLineWidth, leftLineWidth, circle1Color, circle2Color, linesColor) {
    drawCircle(x + width/2, y + height/2, radius1, circle1Width, circle1Color);
    drawCircle(x + width/2, y + height/2, radius2, circle2Width, circle2Color);
    drawLine(x + radius1 + width/2, y + height/2, x + (radius2 + endLineWidth) + width/2, y + height/2, linesColor, leftLineWidth);
    drawLine(x - radius1 + width/2, y + height/2, x - (radius2 + endLineWidth) + width/2, y + height/2, linesColor, rightLineWidth);
    drawLine(x + width/2, y + radius1 + height/2, x + width/2, y + (radius2 + endLineWidth) + height/2, linesColor, bottomLineWidth);
    drawLine(x + width/2, y - radius1 + height/2, x + width/2, y - (radius2 + endLineWidth) + height/2, linesColor, topLineWidth);
}

function drawLine( startX, startY, endX, endY, color, width ) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
    ctx.lineTo(endX,endY);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawCircle( x, y, radius, lineWidth, strokeColor ) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc( x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawBorder( x, y, width, height, lineWidth, strokeColor ) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    ctx.strokeRect( x, y, width, height);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawRect( x, y, width, height, fillColor ) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
    ctx.fillRect( x, y, width, height );
    ctx.restore();
}





newGame();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have had a look and made some changes, but then testing it I found that I made the wrong assumptions about how you intend the game to work. You will have to spell out what the firing functionality is. Currently it looks like you are targeting many enemy at once, but your firing seems to be at a specific target.I cant work out how you want a enemy targeted for firing at. Also you have 3 questions in one and a lot of code, only one thing at a time. BTW you are doing well.

Comment: @Blindman67 I found a solution to shooting, just needed a single if statement... When collision occurs between bullet and enemy, it checks: if( enemy.isClicked ) and then remove bullet, substract hp from target enemy and so on. :D I also updated the question, now I need to fix multiple targets.